# Image icon and string do not appear in Listview in WPF

Tags: wpf

this is XAMl code
Image Icon and string don't appear in ListView in WPF
What's wrong?

Not only the image, but also other text strings do not appear. Trying other methods says that the ItemSource is overlap.

Is the binding not being applied?

```
<GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Aqua">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Aquamarine" Margin="5">
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="ListviewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                                    <Border x:Name="corner"
                                            CornerRadius="9"
                                            Background="White"
                                            Height="1000">
                                        <ContentPresenter
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            />
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
                <TextBlock Text="I/O Input"
                           FontSize="30" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           Margin="10"/>

                <ListView Style="{StaticResource ListviewStyle}" 
                          x:Name="lv_input">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="InputStatus">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding InputStatus}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="InputName"
                                           DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding InputName}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>
```

this is behind code
Image Icon and string don't appear in ListView in WPF
What's wrong?

Not only the image, but also other text strings do not appear. Trying other methods says that the ItemSource is overlap.

Is the binding not being applied?
enter code here

```
    public partial class IOSetPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData> ListViewItemsCollections { get { return ListViewItemsCollections; } }
    ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData> _ListViewItemsCollections = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData>();

    public IOSetPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListViewItemsCollections.Add(new ListViewItemsData()
        {
            InputStatus = "/Image/inputdisconnect.png",
            InputName = "ASFWQEFAasdfqerwefc"
        });

        lv_input.ItemsSource = ListViewItemsCollections;
    }
    public class ListViewItemsData
    {
        public string InputStatus { get; set; }
        public string InputName { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the example you've provided, it appears you have a typo on the 3rd line of your C# code. The property getter should be returning `_ListViewItemsCollections` like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData> ListViewItemsCollections { get { return _ListViewItemsCollections; } }
```

Also, I noticed that you are using ItemsSource directly, rather than setting the DataContext on the lv_input ListView. Whilst ItemsSource may work after fixing the typo, you may encounter unexpected behavior when trying to use item templates etc...

A more correct (but not perfect) way of doing what you are attempting would look like this:

```
public partial class IOSetPage : Page
{
    IOSetPageView view;

    public IOSetPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        view = new IOSetPageView();
        view.Items.Add(new ListViewItemsData()
        {
            InputStatus = "/Image/inputdisconnect.png",
            InputName = "ASFWQEFAasdfqerwefc"
        });

        lv_input.DataContext = view;
    }
}

public class IOSetPageView
{
    public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData> Items { get; } 
        = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData>();
}

public class ListViewItemsData
{
    public string InputStatus { get; set; }
    public string InputName { get; set; }
}
```

With the XAML for the ListView looking like this:

```
<ListView Style="{StaticResource ListviewStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="lv_input">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="InputStatus">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding InputStatus}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="InputName"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding InputName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Notice how the ItemSource is now bound to the Items property of the view class I created. To improve further, you could implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your ListViewItemsData class which would allow the ListView to update in real time when you modify a property.